# Dialog is not showing before I navigate to another product page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

In the products editing page I have the following in watch:

```
watch: {
   $route: 'fetchProductDetais',
  },
```

So when you select another product from drop-down it opens another product editor by id and using the same component. It works fine. Route looks like this:

```
/products/edit/productId
```

The problem is that I want to show a dialog with the above code. So when data is changed and you click another item it should show dialog for notifying about saving changes. I tried to use beforeRoutUpdate but it's not working. It always changes ids without showing dialog. Here is the code for that part as well:

```
hasUnsavedChanges() {
      if (this.dataCahnged.length > 0) {
        return dialog.confirm({
          message: `
            You have unsaved changes, don't forget to save them.
          `,
          confirmText: 'Save',
          cancelText: 'Cancel',
          onConfirm: () => this.update(),
          onCancel: () => this.cancel(),
        })
      }
    },
```

I think this must be used:

```
 beforeRouteUpdate (to, from , next) {
    next()
},
```

The question is how can I implement it correctly so based on condition it will check and show dialog before updating product id in the route and also not harming $route which I set inside watch

Totally component looks like this:

```
  watch: {
       $route: 'fetchProductDetais',
      },

methods: {

fetchProductDetais(){
...
}

 hasUnsavedChanges() {
          if (this.dataCahnged.length > 0) {
            return dialog.confirm({
              message: `
                You have unsaved changes, don't forget to save them.
              `,
              confirmText: 'Save',
              cancelText: 'Cancel',
              onConfirm: () => this.update(),
              onCancel: () => this.cancel(),
            })
          }
        },

  update(){...}

  cancel(){...}
}
```

So how correctly add beforeRoutUpdate the will work with hasunSavedChangesand will not crash detchProductDetails attached inside watch which works fine and every time when you click another product from dropdown it navigates to new :productId page and fetches details for that new product perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The `beforeRouteLeave` hook might work here. No `watch`es necessary:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    confirmed: false
  }),

  computed: {
    hasUnsavedChanges() {
      if (this.dataCahnged.length > 0) {
        return dialog.confirm({
          message: `
            You have unsaved changes, don't forget to save them.
          `,
          confirmText: 'Save',
          cancelText: 'Cancel',

          onConfirm: () => {
            this.update();
            this.confirmed = true;
          },
          
          onCancel: () => {
            this.cancel();
            this.confirmed = false;
          },
        })
      }
    }
  },

  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    // Returning false here will simply abort the current navigation
    next(this.confirmed);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I need to use beforeRouteUpdate because route is the same only productId param is getting changed.

Comment: @NewTechLover Which part of the code that actually triggers the dialog and/or when is it?

Comment: Please add how you are `push`ing  onto the routes or switching across different products. In my example, I'm assuming it happens as you are leaving the current route/page (usually so). It'd be helpful if you can create a quick jsfiddle for it, so that we can test and verify.

Comment: I've updated the question code and added even more explanation can you please check it carefully?

Comment: Actually, why do you need to toggle the dialog's visibility by router at all? Is there any specific reason why a simple state toggling within `data` isn't applicable here?

Comment: Because I need it when user tries to navigate in other product settings page and that dialog will appear before navigating by notifying about saving changes or discarding changes before the navigating to the next product

Comment: So there's your answer: You wanted the dialog to appear **as user tries to navigate to other product settings page** which means it simply won't show up until that happens. You might want to resort to `data` states (as I mentioned earlier) or -- read up here on how to [pass props to route components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components).